# Can every definite integral be computed symbolically?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If all attempts to compute a definite integral appear to lead nowhere, then can we be sure that the integral can at least be expressed as an infinite sum or product of some kind even though we seem unable to find it?

Thinking about this, a definite integral is a number (rational or otherwise). If it's irrational then we would presumably need some kind of infinite product or sum to compute it.

Comment: When we can't find a finite solution (closed form) we usually find an infinite one but I don't see how to prove this in general. An idea, if your function is 'smooth enough' and the integral convergent, could be to use [Euler-Maclaurin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula) to write it as a series (you may have to convert a finite interval to $(1,\infty)$ and obtain a convergent series first). The remainder with Bernoulli terms may be divergent...

Comment: The Riemann integral of a continuous function can be written as an infinite sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/7/2/a/72a1058ad2087aec467af24bddcf9479.png, since every convergent definite integral can be expressed as the infinite sum, perhaps this is the simplest explanation.

Comment: But what about when $b=\infty$...